# Проблемы с val(): как добавить значение к полю по нажатию на кнопку вместо его перезаписи

Tags: javascript, jquery, форма

[image: Сама форма]

Есть вот такая форма, нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии на цифры справа они добавлялись в поле "Ваши доли", я написал скрипт но при нажатии допустим на число "5" в поле пишет "5", при нажатии еще на одно число например "34" оно ту цифру "5" перезаписывает на "34", а нужно чтобы оно добавлялось через запятую например "5,34". Как такое сделать ?

Comment: стоит [минимальный пример кода создать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (одно поле, одна/две кнопки) и добавить его в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

В чём проблема к старому val прибавить ещё текст?

```
var val = $('#elem').val();
var new_val = 34;
$('#elem').val(val+','+new_val);
```

Comment: вы не поняли, там может быть значений максимум 150, то есть я справа клацаю по цифрах, и они в поле через запятую добавляются.

Comment: В моём варианте, так и будет происходить

Comment: в вашем варианте я так понял можно выбрать только 2 числа, а если человек захочет выбрать 15 или 100